# can't be able to import module while having modules on different folders in python

Tags: python, path, pathlib

I'm having project structure like below

```
code
 |
 -- core --
 |        |
 |        test1.py
 |        test2.py
 |---database--        
 |            |
 |            sample.py
 --main.py
```

`main.py` is entry point for my application, from `main.py` I can import test1 from folder core by following code
from core import test1 and it works fine
But when I try to `import test2 from test1(both are on same folder core)`
I'm using the following in test1

```
import test2 
but I'm getting no module named test2 error
```

why is that so?

```
How can I import sample.py in database from test1.py module in core ?
```

Comment: Your import is absolute (actually relative to the entries in `sys.path` which automatically includes your `code` folder). Use a relative import: `import .test2`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have inside these files? Functions? Classes?
You can try:

in `test1.py`: `from .test2 import *`

and in `sample.py`: `from ..core.test1 import *`

Answer (score 0):

First of all: [Import statement docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)

There are **4** main ways you can import **modules** or **module attributes** using `import` statement:

1. Absolute module import `import module_name.submodule.submodule`
2. Absolute limited import `from module_name.submodule import module_attribute, module`
3. Relative limited import `from .submodule import module_attribute, module`
4. Relative wildcard import `from .submodule import *`

What you should know **for now**: absolute imports resolves path from project root. In your case `import test2` is telling python to load `code/test2.py` instead of `code/core/test2.py`. To fix this issue, either supply proper absolute path:

`import core.test2`

or switch to relative path:

- `from . import test2` if you import from `code/core/test1.py`
- `from .core import test2` if you import from `code/main.py`
- `from ..core import test2` if you import from `code/database/sample.py`

**Warning**: be aware of cyclic imports:

```py
from .b import *
```

```py
from .a import *
```